# How can I show only one MIN date?

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to show only the minimal date depends on each projectID, but the result is showing more than one. How can I show only one record?

```
Select DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(p.StartDate) - 1), p.StartDate), p.ProjectID
from pm_project p
where ProjectID = 19                                    
group by p.ProjectID, p.StartDate
Having DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(p.StartDate) - 1), p.StartDate) = MIN(p.StartDate)
```

Comment: Use `SELECT TOP 1 ...` ?  You might want to add sample data to your question.

Comment: remove `p.StartDate` from the `GROUP BY`

Comment: Cannot remove p.StartDate from the GROUP BY because it is needed, else will return the error msg

Comment: If I try to use Top 1, it will only show the record of the earliest date. That isn't what I'm trying to do. I need to get each project ID's min date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use RANK() to get the minimal date for each ProjectID separately:

```
SELECT Date, ProjectID FROM (   
    Select DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(p.StartDate) - 1), p.StartDate) AS Date, p.ProjectID,
        RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY p.ProjectID ORDER BY DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(p.StartDate) - 1), p.StartDate)) AS rank
    from pm_project p
    where ProjectID = 19                                    
    group by p.ProjectID, p.StartDate
    Having DATEADD(DAY, -(DAY(p.StartDate) - 1), p.StartDate) = MIN(p.StartDate)
) ranked
WHERE rank = 1
```

Here the inner query is your query with an extra rank column, which contains the position of the date in the ordered list of dates for each ProjectID separately. You can read the function quite literraly: rank the lines order by the dates and partitioned by the ProjectID.

From this, you will have to select every field where rank = 1, meaning you select the first (minimal) date for each ProjectID.